# Yii Cgridview CColumn button visibiity

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I am creating hospital System..

Here when admitted patient's discharge date is null, then only i want to make visible DISCHARGE button in Cgrid view CColumn Button.

discharge date is going into ***indoor*** model.

PatientController Code:

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Patient('search');

    $discharge_date=Indoor::model()->find(array('condition'=>'patient_id=:id','params'=>array(':id'=>????????????)));

    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Patient']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Patient'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'discharge_date'=>$discharge_date->discharge_date,
    ));
}
```

patient/admin:

```
array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',

        'template'=>'{update} {view} {collection} {discharge}',

        'buttons'=>array
         (

            'collection' => array
            (
                'label'=>'Collection',
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("invoice/index", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                'options'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-success btn-mini'),
            ),


           'discharge' => array
            (
                'label'=>'Discharge',
                 'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("invoice/index", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                'options'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-info btn-mini'),
                'visible'=>'is_null($discharge_date)?true:false;'
            ),

        ),
```

please tell should i use for loop to get each patient's id in controller?? now i have written '?????????' for it..

n what is error in visible code???

thanks in advance..

Comment: This is not a CGridView problem. You should use a relation in Patient model.

Comment: i have used relation in model...n in admin i can print discharge_date also.."visible" syntax is giving error...

Comment: Show us your Patient relations, and eventually the search function

Comment: What should I pass in data provider for CGrid view?? error is coming at this point..

Answer (score 0):

remove single quote then it will work fine...try this

```
'visible'=> is_null($discharge_date)?true:false
```

Comment: Still it is giving following error..   "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given"

Comment: 'discharge' => array
          (
              'label'=>'Discharge',
              // 'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/followup.png',
              'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("invoice/index", array("id"=>$data->id))',
              'options'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-info btn-mini'),
              'visible'=> is_null($discharge_date)?true:false,
              
          ), i have written this code...n i have posted my error in above comment..

Comment: can you print $discharge_date value?